# stop the CSS filter property cascading

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I tried to make box-shadow affect work cross browsers, in order to make ie work I used "filter" property but the effect cascades to the child element (in my case a span) I tried to stop it by using `filter : none` but it didn't work searched the web but I couldn't find a solution. please help me solve this problem.

HTML code :

```
<div id="shadow">
            <span>text text</span>             
</div>
```

CSS code :

```
#shadow{
 -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
 /* For IE 8 */
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
 /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set background color

```
#shadow{
 -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
 background:#ffffff;
 /* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
}
```

Comment: That only works if you don't care about your background being white.  You'd have to manually set the background everywhere this is used, and I find that annoying.  Is there any other way to keep the filter property from cascading, and creating ugly text-shadows on the child span element text?